# XOR Encryption Gives Different Result When Encrypting and Decrypting

Tags: encryption, vb6

I want to encrypt a file. I use XOR to Encrypt it. But, the problem is, i can encrypt it, but when i want to decrypt it, it gives me different result (not the original file)

Here is the code that i use

```
Public Function Encrypt(ByVal txt As String, ByVal pass As String) As String
Dim mem() As Byte
mem = StrConv(txt, vbFromUnicode)
For i = 0 To UBound(mem)
    mem(i) = Asc(mem(i)) Xor Asc(Mid(pass, (i Mod Len(pass)) + 1, 1))
Next i
Encrypt = StrConv(mem, vbUnicode)
Erase mem
End Function

Public Function Decrypt(ByVal txt As String, ByVal pass As String) As String
Dim mem() As Byte
mem = StrConv(txt, vbFromUnicode)
For i = 0 To UBound(mem)
    mem(i) = Asc(mem(i)) Xor Asc(Mid(pass, (i Mod Len(pass)) + 1, 1))
Next i
Decrypt = StrConv(mem, vbUnicode)
Erase mem
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
Enkrip = Encrypt(txt.LoadFile("C:\mom.txt"), "FROM YOUR SON")
dekrip = Decrypt(Enkrip, "FROM YOUR SON")

MsgBox Enkrip & vbCrLf & dekrip
End Sub
```

The value of dekrip should be the original content of C:\mom.txt, but it returns different result

---

I also tried this code, and it works well

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Data = "A"
pass = "B"

enkrip = Chr(Asc(Data) Xor Asc(pass))
dekrip = Chr(Asc(enkrip) Xor Asc(pass))

MsgBox enkrip & vbCrLf & dekrip
End Sub
```

---

What should I do to fix my code?

Thanks

Comment: Step through the code and examine the values as you do, best to examine them in hex. Take some time to understand character encodings and values.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are made of characters, not bytes, and in VB6 characters are 16 bits. This creates possible conflicts when you `XOR` two sets of characters in the ASCII domain, because the conversion to and from Unicode can cause patterns that do not transfer well across the Unicode--ASCII boundary.

You should read the file into a byte array, do your `XOR`, and output it as a byte array, avoiding the conversion to/from Unicode that occurs when you read/write text to a file. You can still use the `StrConv` of the `Pass` variable because even if it's garbled by the conversion it will be garbled the same way every time.

Be aware that if you change national language systems between encode and decode, the `StrConv` step can cause a different 'garbling' and so may fail.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, when you are using XOR for encryption, you are merely flipping the bits based on a passed bitmask.  For that reason, you don't need a encrypt and a decrypt - they both do the same thing.  I haven't scoured your code, but there's two possibilities: One is that one of the two works and the other does not - figure out which one works by calling it twice and make that one your encryption method.  If they both fail, they it's likely the fact that your converting your first parameter to unicode, but not taking the same step (or assumption) in your second parameter.  While that would be syntactically correct, it would probably still run, just not return what you'd think.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake lies in

```
(i Mod Len(pass)) + 1)
```

you should better have something like

```
1 + ((i-1) mod len(Pass))
```

and for from **1** to **m** here you do **0** to **m** so it seems like you go one step to far.

Either you go from **1** to **ubound** or from **0** to **ubound - 1**